# C client socket does not output/connect to tcp server

Tags: c

Why does this header file go into a freeze state or it does not output anything even if the server is accepting connection form other scripts/tools

`tcpclient.h`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#pragma once

int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

int init_client()
{
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  

    if (socket_desc < 0 )
    {
        printf("Failed to create socket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int connection(char *host,int port )
{

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);

    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))<0)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect @ %s:%d\n",host,port);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Connected to [%s:%d]\n",host,port);
    return 0;
}
```

using a `main.c` like so

```
int main()
{
    int soc = init_client();
    int con = connection("192.168.0.12",6666);
    return 0;
}
```

the only warning I get is that the variable `soc` is not used

Comment: If `connect` fails, check `errno` to see what's wrong. Use e.g. `strerror` to get a printable string of the error.

Comment: Also, did `socket` succeed? As for `connect` , if `socket` fails you need to check `errno` to check what problems you have.

Comment: typically a header file `.h` does not contain code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried adding `printf("%d\n",errno);` but still no output in the console and no connection on the server

Comment: @stark I know but i am not developing a production library I am just learning here

Comment: Do you mean that `connect` *blocks*? That it doesn't return? How long have you waited?

Comment: And have you looked at what happens on the other side of the connection?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I think it blocks the timeout in the server is 1 min but the c  executable is running for more than 10 min already and the server console does not contain any connections

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you define the functions in a *header file?*

Comment: And just to clarify, how do you run your (client) program? If you run from a command-lien terminal, you don't get *any* output at all (from the code exactly as you show it)? And you don't get the prompt back? The program just hangs and you can't write other commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program works correctly in my computer.... It's not clear what do you claim on.

Anyway, after tweaking it a bit, I have some points to comment on it.  I changed the ip address to 127.0.0.1 and port to 80 and started an apache server locally to check that the server is, indeed ready to accept connections.

First I checked that the connection opened locally with a `telnet(1)` command (you will probably have to install it in your machine as it is not installed now by default)

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> close
Connection closed.
$ _
```

then I changed several things in your code (they should not affect the run, but they will make you trouble in the future if you don't take this path)

- I first created a `socket.h` file to put prototypes for both functions, so you don't run in trouble if you later change the prototypes.

#### socket.h

```
#ifndef _SOCKET_H
#define _SOCKET_H

int init_client(void);
int connection(const char *host, int port);

#endif /* _SOCKET_H */
```

```
As you see, I changed the parameter `host` into a `const char *` type, so the compiler knows that the string is not changed inside the function and can optimize calls, based on that.
```

- Second, I `#include`d the file in both modules, so if you change the interface, both modules (provider and consumer) know about the interface change.

#### socket.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
```

I used the last two includes to use `strerror(errno)`, that gives you the reason for the connection error (mainly being a connection refused error)

```
#include "socket.h"

int socket_desc = -1;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
```

this is not good practice.  A better solution would be to return the socket and pass it as parameter to the connection call below.  Using global variables will run you into trouble later if you want to use these functions in different threads, as the socket_desc global variable is common to all the threads you will have.

```
int init_client(void)
{
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socket_desc < 0 )
    {
        printf("Failed to create socket, %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int connection(const char *host, int port)
{

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);

    printf("trying connect to %s:%d\n", host, port);

    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))<0)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect @ %s:%d, %s\n",
                host, port, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
```

printing here the reason of the non connection is a good idea to know what is happening.

```
    }
    printf("Connected to [%s:%d]\n",host,port);
    return 0;
}
```

A better solution would be the following:

#### socket.c

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "socket.h"

int init_client(void)
{
    int socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socket_desc < 0 )
    {
        printf("Failed to create socket: %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
    }
    return socket_desc;
}

int connection(int sd, const char *host, int port)
{

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);

    printf("trying connect to %s:%d\n", host, port);

    if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to connect @ %s:%d, %s\n",
                host, port, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Connected to [%s:%d]\n", host, port);
    return 0;
}
```

where `socket.h` becomes:

#### socket.h

```
#ifndef _SOCKET_H
#define _SOCKET_H

int init_client(void);
int connection(int socket_descriptor, const char *host, int port);

#endif /* _SOCKET_H */
```

this modifications, made that calling the program to `localhost:80` resulted in:

```
$ a.out
trying connect to 127.0.0.1:80
Connected to [127.0.0.1:80]
$ _
```

while using 79 as the port resulted in:

```
$ a.out
trying connect to 127.0.0.1:79
Failed to connect @ 127.0.0.1:79, Connection refused
Failed connection(), Connection refused
$ _
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation and extra tips but can you elaborate more on the second point I don't fully get what you mean by 

Second, I #included the file in both modules, so if you change the interface, both modules (provider and consumer) know about the interface change.

Comment: Including the `#include` directive in both files (client and provider) warrants that the definition in provider module and client module **is exactly the same** (for example, you defined the `init_client()` using an empty parameter list, which means _undefined parameter list_, not an empty one --- which is defined specifying `void` as the parameter list)  That approach ensures that if you change one side only, you'll get an error.

Comment: can I use `#pragma once ` instead of using `#ifndef ... #endif`

Comment: you can, but probably you  will run in trouble if you get a compiler that doesn't understand that pragma.  I'm not sure if Visual C understands it, for example.  Today all popular compilers are derived in some way or another from GCC or CLANG, but despite of that fact, you can run in an environment in which you have to use a compiler that doesn't support the `#pragma once`.